# C# Linq Include() with where()

Tags: c#, linq

Have a query that looks something like this

```
var myResult = await _context.Families.AsNoTracking().AsSplitQuery()
                    .Include(f => f.Dogs.Where(d => d.Name == "someName"))
                    .Where(f => f.Breed == "some breed")
                    .Where(f => f.Dogs.Count > 0)
                    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Have used dummy data*

In my query I'm finding that the include statement works as expected however the last .Where() is not. **I intent to filter all 'families' where they have a dog with name == "someName" and breed == "some breed". The main point being, I only want to return dogs in the dog list where the name == "someName"**

I'm finding that that last Where() clause is doing a .count on the entire list of dogs and not the filtered included dogs we want in the response.

Can of course replicate the `f.Dogs.Where(mp => mp.Name == "someName")` inside the last .Where() but is there no way to do it without repeating the logic.

- Split Query is required. Query is much larger with multiple includes, but shortened it for post

What am I missing

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to EF 4.x / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x / 7.x / 8.x? What database provider? Can you show the SQL that is being generated?

Comment: You have to repeat filter logic or use library like `LINQKit` for correcting Expression Tree.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem we found was that the second `.Where(f => f.Dogs.Count > 0)` was not doing a count on the included Dogs, but instead doing a count on all Dogs. The answer, although there is duplication looks something like this.

```
var myResult = await _context.Families.AsNoTracking().AsSplitQuery()
                    .Include(f => f.Dogs.Where(d => d.Name == "someName"))
                    .Where(f => f.Breed == "some breed")
                    .Where(f => f.Dogs.Count.Any(d => d.Name == "someName"))
                    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

basically have to just diplucated the include .where() in the outer .where()

Comment: Maybe `.Where(f => f.Dogs.Any(d => d.Name == "someName"))` ?

Comment: Sorry type, yes above is correct, will ammend @GuruStron

Answer (score -2):

*Given that you have shorted your query for the post, what I am about to say may or may not apply.*

**Warning** Include only works if the there is a database relationship between Families and Dogs (*which I assume there is*).

This query could be simplified so that you are not running multiple queries on the database.  Will this query help you?

```cs
    var myResult = await _context.Families
                    .Join(Dogs, fam => fam.Id, dog => dog.FamilyId, 
                            (fam, dog) => new { fam, dog })
                    .Join(Breeds, a => a.dog.BreedId, breed => breed.Id, 
                            (a, breed) => new { 
                                Family = a.fam,
                                Dog = a.Dog, 
                                Breed = breed 
                            })
                    .Where(m => m.Dog.Name == "someName"
                        && m => Breed.Name == "some breed")
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken)
                    .GroupBy(g => g.Family)
                    .Where(r => r.Count() > 0);
```

This will allow you to query without putting sub-selects in your where clause which are very inefficient.  The ToList or ToListAsync will cause your query to run.  You get your results, then you can filter out any families that do not have at least one dog.  Granted I may have assumed something or missed something else not knowing your exact schema.  If you want more help, let me know your basic schema and I can try to come up with something else.

Comment: Given that the OP is using some form of EF, using `Join` is not productive.

Comment: @NetMage if you watch the SQL that EF writes, you will see what I'm talking about.